# NextJS Image Component relative image from NetlifyCMS markdown

Tags: next.js, netlify-cms, nextjs-image

I keep receiving an error in NextJS when trying to use the image component with data from NetlifyCMS. Does anyone know how to ensure there's a leading slash to the image url that is generated into markdown. The error I keep receiving is

```
Error: Failed to parse src "img/occasions-thumb.jpg" on `next/image`, if using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an absolute URL
```

The markdown it is using is:

```
 ---
title: New Title
intro: blabbidy blah blah intro text
image: img/occasions-thumb.jpg
---
```

Component looks like:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    let { title, intro, image } = attributes;
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <script src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
        </Head>
        <article>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>{intro}</p>
          <Image
            src={image}
            alt={title}
            width="600"
            height="500"
            layout="responsive"
          />        
        </article>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And config.yml is:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main
media_folder: public/img
public_folder: /img

collections:
  - label: "Pages"
    name: "pages"
    files:
      - label: "Home"
        name: "home"
        file: "content/home.md"
        fields:
          - {label: Title, name: title, widget: string}
          - {label: Intro text, name: intro, widget: text}
          - {label: Image, name: image, widget: image}
```

If i just manually add a leading slash to the image url in the markdown it parses fine, but obviously that's not a solution since I would like to use the CMS.